# Is this the correct way to search in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. t1 and t2. I want to select the values that are from t1 and occurred in t2. What I wrote is the following:

```
select col1 from t1, t2
where t1.col1y=t2.col2;
```

Is this is the right way to search for the value ?

Comment: If you perform it - does it return the expected results?

Comment: In toy example yes. But there is confusing huge db that cause me doubts.

Comment: if it returns the expected results - then it is the correct way of doing that. Yes, it is that simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that works, but it's the old form of writing a join. Use the new form:

```
select t1.col1
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

Comment: What is "the old form"? They both are valid forms and I haven't heard some of them is more preferred than another (at least from mysql's documentation or dev team)

Comment: Declaring the parent table and it's associations with others via joins are more specific and reliable is the first part of the answer to that.

Comment: @zerkms: The "old form" is the way that joins were written before the `join` command existed. The industry is moving away from that syntax. It has been deprecated in SQL Server and Oracle, so it's not unlikely that MySQL will also go that way.